# Getting the name of content block

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We can easily get the name of [Impression Region](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_impression_region_dynamic.htm&type=5) using the **%%_ImpressionRegionName%%** [Personalisation String](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5). This works fine for Impression Regions defined with Ampscript or with Dynamic Content. However, if a link is placed in a regular content block, is there a way of identifying the name of this block? The Personalisation String list does not provide any examples for this use case.

I need to provide context in which a link is clicked, preferably dynamically - to be used in [Web Analytics Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_wa_web_analytics_connector.htm&type=5). I know, that I can provide this information in **%%linkname%%** - but being able to fetch the content block name would be beneficial (also for other use cases)

Comment: looking at the GA360 parameters its using %%_contentAssetID%%  so unsure if you can add that to your WAC string to populate, it doesn't validate in an email though

Comment: %%_contentAssetID%% isn't event being parsed, and shows with %% in the URL. Quite strange