# Get Content Name via AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to dynamically append the content name into a URL string parameter (utm_content) for all inbound links in our emails.  The catch here is that some of our content blocks are built dynamically.  I'm hoping to find a way to retrieve the content name using ampscript.  This would be the equivalent of `%%emailname_%%` but instead of pulling the name of the email, I want to pull the name of the content block in which the ampscript function is contained.  I've found the `%%_ImpressionRegionByName%%` personalization string.  This will work for dynamic content but doesn't work for static content.  Is there a way to just pull that content name via ampscript?

Comment: I've raised a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274323/getting-the-name-of-content-block) last year, unfortunately with no good answers

Comment: Thanks Lukas - I've opened a support case with Salesforce.  If I get a better answer, I'll post it here.

Comment: I get the feeling the answer is gonna be that you cannot get content block name via personalization string. My guess is it is going to be due to the fact that the pre-compiler that creates the 'snapshot' of the email before it goes in the send queue pushes these blocks into a single 'email' so then when your AMPScript runs it is no longer in a block but part of the 'email snapshot' - making it impossible for you to grab any context from the block itself. This is all best guesses, so I could be completely wrong.

Comment: here's the response from Salesforce: There isn't currently a personalization string that contains the content block name. You would need to manually add it to an AMPScript variable in order to access it. If you believe that this should be a feature, you can submit it to the IdeaExchange. If an idea gets enough votes, our Product team will consider it for development